# How to send a vector with Service Client Communication?

Tags: ros, communication, ros-kinetic, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

How can I send a hole vector in once(not one by one of each entries) from client to the service ? is it possible?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293247/how-to-send-a-vector-with-service-client-communication?/) by [Developer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31478/developer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2018-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes this is possible.

You can define a variable in a service or message definition as a vector by adding empty square brackets after the type, eg:

```
int32[] myVectorOfInts
```

So in your case to send a vector of values to a service provider from the client your service definition could look something like this:

```
string singleVariable
int32[] vectorOfIntegers
std_msgs/ColorRGBA[] vectorOfAnotherMessage
---
int32 variableReturnedToClient
```

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Developer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31478/developer/) on 2018-06-05**:
Thanks! it helped